# PEER_ID_INVALID in sending Message to userid

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm using `TLSharp` to create a client for Telegram and i want to send messages to some telegram users.
i have their `username` and `userid` to use, but i can't find a way to just use their `username` to send them a message (although in telegram api you can do this but i couldn't find a way to do it with `TLSharp`), so i use their `userid` to send them a message with this code:

```
await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerUser() { user_id = someOneUserid }, "This is My Message");
```

this code works find with people that i have them in my contact list but with the others i got `PEER_ID_INVALID` exception.

is there a way to add these people to contact list before sending them a message? or is there a way to just use their `username`?

thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the thread is not active anymore but for who viewing this page in future :

You need AccessHash to send message :

```
await client.SendMessageAsync( new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = xxx, AccessHash = yyyyy}, "This is My Message");
```

If you don't know the access hash , just try to resolve the user with username or phone number. (TLUser class)

If you have the TLUser object you can use this :

```
UserId = user.Id
AccessHash = user.AccessHash.Value
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to import a list of contacts by mobile number:

```
contacts.importContacts#da30b32d contacts:Vector<InputContact> replace:Bool = contacts.ImportedContacts;
```

Use this to resolve by username:

```
contacts.resolveUsername#f93ccba3 username:string = contacts.ResolvedPeer;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as i mentioned before i dont have their phone number only `username` and `userid`

Comment: i'm not sure what is this line means, do you use TLSharp before? how can i send this request to telegram?

Comment: i am showing you how to do it directly from the Telegram API

Comment: You can edit yout TLsharp to include this method if it does not already.